# Remove space from print output - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this..

```
the_tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
print ('\"',the_tuple[1],'\"')
```

showing

```
" 2 "
```

How can I get the output to show `"2"`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
print ('\"',the_tuple[1],'\"', sep='')
                               ^^^^^^
```

Note that those escapes are completely unnecessary:

```
print ('"', the_tuple[1], '"', sep='')
```

Or even better, use string formatting:

```
print ('"{}"'.format(the_tuple[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another f-string example,

```
the_tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
print(f'"{the_tuple[1]}"')
```

gives

```
"2"
```